# Enable on-screen keyboard from the command line

Tags: 10.04, keyboard

My keyboard just broke down, so I wanted to enable the on-screen keyboard, found in "Universal settings", via the command line (by logging in to that PC via ssh)....

Unfortunately, I cannot find any guidance to doing that - any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SSH to add the onboard screen keyboard to the list of startup application.
To do so you should simply create a .display file within ~/.config/autostart directory.
The onboard.display file should contain:

> [Desktop Entry]
>   Type=Application
>   Exec=onboard
>   Hidden=false
>   NoDisplay=false
>   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
>   Name=Onboard Keyboard
>   Comment=

Save it and restart (`sudo shutdown -r now`).

Comment: Awesome @yossile, many thanks for the answer! For some reason, I missed the message when you posted the answer, which is why I accept it so late, sorry about that.. Thanks again - cheers!